# Which is more correct: "CLR Type", "CLI Type" or ".NET Type"?

Tags: .net, clr, terminology

I'm working on a library that has multiple notions of "type".

I'm trying to find and use the most correct way to refer to a type defined in a .NET language like C# or VB.NET.

Would it be more correct to refer to those types as "CLR types", as "CLI types" or as ".NET types"?

In other words, is the typing system part of the Common Language Runtime, or Infrastructure, or part of some other layer in the .NET stack?

Answer (score 0):

I just answered my question after more Googling.

Types are defined in the [Common Type System (CTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Type_System), which is a part of the [Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure), which is then interpreted by the [Common Language Runtime (CLR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime).

The exact terminology to use may be opinionated, but on a theoretical level the correct options seem to be either "CTS Type" or "CLI Type", depending on context and specificity.